# create service that pass data between different component in angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

i try to create service that pass date between component but it only work within the component.

```
@Injectable()
 export class SelectedDateService {
           private checkin = new Subject<string>();
           checkin$ = this.checkin.asObservable();
           private checkout = new Subject<string>();
           checkout$ = this.checkout.asObservable();
           setCheckIn (start: string)  {  
                      this.checkin.next(start);
                                        }
           setCheckOut (end: string) {  
                     this.checkout.next(end); }
                     }
```

in first component i setup my service in constructor method and i called in 
ngOnInit method

```
constructor(  private dateselectService: SelectedDateService) { }
      ngOnInit() {
           this.dateselectService.checkin$.subscribe(
           checkin => {this.date.checkIn = checkin;});
           this.dateselectService.checkout$.subscribe(
           checkout => {this.date.checkOut = checkout;});
              }
```

and in my input field in html i add click event that takes input date and set date in service

```
 onDateChanged(event) {
                if (event.formatted !== '' || event !== undefined ){
                      this.selected = '#26a69a';
                      this.selectedText = event.formatted ;
                      this.dateselectService.setCheckIn(event.formatted );
                   }else {
                      this.selectedText = '';
                              }
                       }
```

the reason i add getter in ngOninit method just to get date if it has been set before.
**note that i did the same with the second component to get any date had been set already by first component**

Comment: What's the problem? Would you mind formatting the code properly?

Comment: i am try to store date in this service and used as input in second component but in same time if user decide to go to home page which has the  first component, the first component should already has this input has value or whatever value if value has been updated in second component,

Comment: also note that two component have two different route

Comment: Make sure you do not have the service  in the `@Componet ({ providers[...] })` list for either of the two components you want to share the service between.  If you do that then a new service instance is created for each of the two components.  Instead the service should be in the providers list of some parent component that contains both components of interest, or in the root NgModule /bootstrap if it is 'global'.

Comment: i already have that set up